# Grub2 option in a Dell xps 13 9310 with ubuntu 20.04

Tags: grub2, 20.04

According to Dell's indications, there must be a partition on my computer with a possibility to diagnose the system through Grub2.
But when I do the test with the F12 Grub button it does not appear and it takes me to the BIOS where there is no such option.

I do not know what to do to be able to have that option.
Can someone give me some help?

Thanks

JOsef

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On page 58 of [the service manual](https://dl.dell.com/topicspdf/xps-13-9310-laptop_service-manual_en-us.pdf), Dell lists these instructions:

> This diagnostic is the new on-board diagnostic tool and replaces the ePSA 3.0 diagnostics. It has a clean and modern user interface, quicker tests, simplified messaging.
> SupportAssist | On-board Diagnostics can be initiated by one of the following methods:
>
> - Pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> to enter one-time Boot Menu and selecting Diagnostics to initiate the diagnostics OR <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Power</kbd>
> - BIOS POST detecting a hardware failure or error and initiating the diagnostics
>
> The SupportAssist | On-board Diagnostics is embedded with the BIOS and is launched by the BIOS internally. The embedded system diagnostics provides a set of options for particular devices or device groups allowing you to:
>
> - Run tests in either Quick Test Mode or Advanced Test Mode
> - Run thorough tests to introduce additional test options to provide extra information about the failed device(s)
> - Run tests in either Automatic Mode or Interactive Test Mode
> - Run interactive tests on LCD panel and keyboard
> - Display or save test results
> - View status messages that indicate if the tests are completed successfully
> - View error messages that indicate if problems were encountered during the test
>
> **NOTE:** Some tests for specific devices require user interaction. Ensure that you are present at the computer terminal when the diagnostic tests are performed.
>
> For more information, see SupportAssist Pre-Boot System Performance Check.

This appears to be built into the motherboard, much in the same way Apple has done it for their systems. No partitions to accidentally delete